# How can I use Promise.race or Promise.all with async iterables?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Code sample should explain better than words can:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const start = new Date();
(async()=>{
        const proc = spawn('( echo a; >&2 echo b; sleep 1; echo c; >&2 echo d )', { shell:true });
        proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
        proc.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
        for await (const data of proc.stdout) {
                console.log(new Date() - start, "proc stdout:", data);
        }
        for await (const data of proc.stderr) {
                console.log(new Date() - start, "proc stderr:", data);
        }
})();
```

The output here sees the stderr coming out at the end, which can be fine for many use cases, but I'm very curious about how to get undelayed output from both streams. For example, the behavior observed is:

```
5 'proc stdout:' 'a\n'
1006 'proc stdout:' 'c\n'
1009 'proc stderr:' 'b\nd\n'
```

This makes sense because the async flow execution does not reach the second for loop until stdout is fully consumed.

I'm imagining that Promise.all or race could be used to construct a way to achieve what I want, but it's not materializing in front of me. Also, are for await loops the only way to access async iterables cleanly?

Answer (score 2):

Put each `for await` into an async IIFE, so you can get a Promise out of each. Then you can call `Promise.all` or `Promise.race` on them:

```
proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
proc.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
const stdoutProm = (async () => {
  for await (const data of proc.stdout) {
    console.log(new Date() - start, "proc stdout:", data);
  }
})();
const stderrProm = (async () => {
  for await (const data of proc.stderr) {
    console.log(new Date() - start, "proc stderr:", data);
  }
})();
await Promise.race([stdoutProm, stderrProm]);
// One of the iterators has been completely consumed
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking me out of that thinking box!

Comment: Do you know if this is the only way to leverage those for await loops? These for loops are clean but I'm worried the IIAAFE's may make this too scary for my coworkers. Is there another way besides rolling a custom Promise and using the event callbacks directly?

Comment: @StevenLu Instead of IIAFEs you could simply have some async helper function like `consumeStream` that contains the for-await. Then you `await Promise.all([consumeStream(proc.stdout),consumeStream(proc.stderr)])` or some such

Comment: @StevenLu Unfortunately, `for await` is the only clean way to iterate over an async iterable. I'm disappointed too. You can also manually call `.next` / check `.done` for each as in the other answer, but it's far uglier IMO. You can abstract the `for await` behind a function, but that doesn't change any of the logic

Answer (score 0):

You could also combine the two iterators into one:

```
 async function* combine(a, b) {
   a = a[Symbol.iterator](); b = b[Symbol.iterator]();
   let doneA = false, doneB = false;
   let itA = a.next().then(a => ({ a })),
          itB = b.next().then(b => ({ b }));
   while(true) {
      const result = await Promise.race([itA, itB]);
      doneA = doneA || result.a && result.a.done;
      doneB = doneB || result.b && result.b.done;
      if(doneA && doneB) return;
      yield [result.a && result.a.value, result.b && result.b.value];

      if(result.a) itA = a.next().then(a => ({ a }))
      else itB = b.next().then(b => ({ b }));
   }
}
```

Usable as:

```
 for await(const [out, err] of combine(std.out, std.err)) {
   if(out) console.log(out);
   if(err) console.log(err);
 }
```

Comment: That's an async generator? I did not know such a thing was possible.